# Оповщение о покупке домена

Tags: хостинг, домен

Вопрос. Часто покупают домены, и бывает что сразу после оплаты получаю на email предложение о создании сайта. Email не принадлежит хостинг компании, а компании которая разрабатывает сайты. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой сервис, где в онлайн режиме можно получить кто и какой купил email? или они в партнерстве с хостинг компанией, правда хостинг компания не признается.